# What does the "for a long time" here mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is a conversation from a book:

> Reporter: Have you just made a new film, Miss Marsh?
>
> Miss Marsh: Yes, I have.
>
> Reporter: Are you going to make another?
>
> Miss Marsh: No, I'm not. I'm going to retire. I feel very tired. I don't want to make another film for a long time.

I don't quite understand the "for a long time" mean. Does it mean that "I just made film but I'm tired so I  don't want to make another for a long time in the future", the "long time" here is from now to the future.

Or does it mean "Actually I didn't want to make any film for a long time", the "long time" is in the past until now.

I found some translation for this is the later option, but I feel it a little strange, and I think it might be the first. Is it right?

Comment: If the long time were in the past, she would probably have said "I **didn't** want to", meaning that her wanting is in the past.  The present tense *don't* means that her wanting is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the first.  If I don't want to do something for a long time, it means that I may want to do it in the future, but not until a long time has passed.  If I *didn't* want to make a film for a long time, that means that during some long period in the past I did not want to make a film--not necessarily until now.  If I wanted to say in the past until now, it would be *I haven't wanted* to make a film for a long time.

Now, if I were to say *I don't want to have to wait for a long time*, I am in most cases saying that I do not want the period which I have to wait to last for a long time, which is something a little bit different.  You can generally work out the meaning from the context provided by the specfic verb used.